# log4net - Log using multiple appenders

Tags: log4net

I want to log messages to TextBox and also to file. I found an example (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43027/Logging-display-and-WPF) that logs to TextBox. I modified the app.config and extend it with another appender.

The config file Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="C:\log4net_internal.log"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="NotifyAppender" type="log4netSample.Logging.NotifyAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="c:\PrestAba.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="NotifyAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

When i run the application and write the log Messages, it only logs TextBox. Is there more modification needed?

Comment: One suggestion is to set log4net.Internal.Debug to true in your appSettings to see how the XMLConfigurator is picking up and reading your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your file name must be escaped to be read:

```
<param name="File" value="c:\\PrestAba.log" />
```

Also, you can condense that to

```
<file value="c:\\PrestAba.log" />
```

Which is a bit more readable and more in line with log4net's intentions of making readable and maintainable XML.